# Loading Components from Routes into layout?

Tags: reactjs

I have this react app i am building, and I am trying to make this app as scalable as possible so i have take the approach of loading components like this into my "AdminLayout" component, but the components dont load when i go to the route. There is no error or anything, and when i console.log the props in the AdminLayout i can see the components that were passed through. Is there a different approach to this, or am i doing this wrong?
Here is are the Routes

```js
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path='/signin' component={c.Sessions.SignIn} />
        <AdminLayout>
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/admin' />
                <Route
                    path='/courses-library'
                    component={c.Admin.CourseLibrary}
                />
            </Switch>
        </AdminLayout>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

```
const AdminLayout = props => (
    <div id='AdminLayout'>
        {console.log(props)}
        <h1>This is the AdminLayout</h1>
        {props.children.props.children}
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Try ```props.children``` rather than ```props.children.props.children```

Comment: @brycelikesdogs I have tried that but it still wont load, sorry i left that after trying everything i could think of